# Rspec - expected #count to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have this feature:

```
feature "Blog features -", type: :feature, js: true do
  let!(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin) }

  scenario "Create new Blog" do
    expect do
      sign_in_as_admin(admin)
      visit "/admin/blogs/new"

      fill_in "blog_title", with: "title"
      fill_in "blog_content", with: "lorem ipsum dolor"
      click_button "Save"
    end.to change(Blog, :count).by(1)
  end

end
```

The Blog is saving correctly on the database but the test is not passing and I get this error: `expected #count to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0`

Comment: try change(Blog.count).from(0).to(1)

Comment: then I get: expected #count to have changed from 0 to 1 - but did not change, but the blog is saving correctly on the db :/

Comment: any reason why you're putting that block of code in an expect? you could move that out and after click_button "Save", expect(Blog.count).to eq(1)

Comment: is Save an AJAX request?  https://robots.thoughtbot.com/automatically-wait-for-ajax-with-capybara

Comment: no, is not an AJAX request

Comment: If it's not an ajax request why are you using js:true?

Comment: If you check with debugger (https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) that blog is really saved to database after line "click_button 'save'" is executed. I think that might help to find out, what is wrong.

Comment: @forthowin this is the correct way to assert something has changed in rspec. The block is valid. I don't want people to get confused by your upvoted comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know enough about your setup to determine if it's an error in the upstream code or if it's simply a race condition. My gut tells me you're racing. Try adding a sleep after the `click save` to see if that helps.

If your test is booting up a second process for your server (which I suspect it is) then your test is firing off a request (to be handled by the server at some future time) and then immediately checking the `blog` count. The request hasn't been handled by your server by the time you're checking the blog count.

Instead of checking the blog count at the database level, I'd recommend checking text or elements on the page. The user is getting some feedback from the save right? Assert against that.